# android localization format string error

Tags: java, android, localization

ive been doing some localization translation for my android app and i got across this error that i don't know how to fix
so the java mainActivity file methode looks like this

```
private String creatOrderSummary(String name, int price, boolean addWhippedCream, boolean addChocolate) {
    String priceMessage = getString(R.string.order_summary_name, name);
    priceMessage += "\nadd whipped cream? " + addWhippedCream;
    priceMessage += "\nadd chocolate? " + addChocolate;
    priceMessage += "\nQuantity : " + quantity;
    priceMessage += "\nTotal : $" + price;
    priceMessage += "\n" + getString(R.string.thank_you);
    return priceMessage;

}
```

and the strings xml file looks like this

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <string name="app_name">Just Java</string>

    <string name="toppings">Toppings</string>
    <string name="thank_you">Thank you!</string>
    <string name="user_name">Name</string>
    <string name="whipped_cream">Whipped Cream</string>
    <string name="chocolate">Chocolate</string>
    <string name="quantity">Quantity</string>
    <string name="order">Order</string>
    <string name="order_summary_name">Name: <xliff:g id="name" example="Amy">%s</xliff:g></string>
</resources>
```

and the problem is on the error i get says

> Format string 'order_summary_name' is not a valid format string so it
>   should not be passed to String.format

Comment: your code is correct. go ahead and run the project. if not okay, try to clean and rebuild your project. this might be because Gradle build is not refreshed yet

Comment: @FazanCheng I have the exact same code as his and this did not solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try getRsources().getString(R.string.name);

Comment: I have the exact same code as his and this did not solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I "cleaned" the project then "Rebuild" and it worked.

So what I did is:
On menu bar (in Android Studio) choose to Build- > Clean Project. 
After that click again on Build - > Rebuild Project.
When it`s done, run "app" (Shift + F10 on Windows).

Comment: Please elebarate to avoid "low quality" flag and explain what "cleaned" meant in your case.. I'm guessing not "cleaning" the car or a kettle. Same for "rebuild". (End of Late Answer Review).

Comment: I have the exact same code as you (Udacity course right ?) and this did not solve the problem. As a result, the name is not shown in the order summary

Comment: Ok found the answer : xliff:g was missing from the localisation file string.xml (fr)   It needed to be added manually